# sys.exit() does not terminate my program

Tags: python

I want to exit a Python script if my try succeeds. My code just doesn't exit and continues to execute the rest of the script.

If I run `python myscript.py --help`, I need the script to exit. If I run `python myscript.py` I need do execute the `except` part.

```
try:
    if sys.argv[1] == '--help' or sys.argv[1] == '-help' or \
            sys.argv[1] == '-h' or sys.argv[1] == '--h':
        print "NAME"
        sys.exit("Usage : python go.py")
except:
    #REST OF THE CODE.
```

Comment: How else would I do it ? And FYI, you are not obligated to repond.

Comment: Try it with the try: except: removed

Comment: Umm... how else would you do it? You would just let the execution finish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would you use a try / except block? Like bereal says, you are catching all exceptions and hiding problems. try /except blocks are for **exceptional** circumstances. Not alternate code paths.

```
def main():
    # main code block

if sys.argv[1] == '--help' or sys.argv[1] == '-help' or \
    sys.argv[1] == '-h' or sys.argv[1] == '--h':
    print "Help text"
else:
    main()
```

Also, as a general rule when using try /except. Just catch the exception that you care about. It's impossible to debug something that cannot even tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 10):

As the [docs say](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exit), `sys.exit` in fact does nothing but raising `SystemExit` and you're intercepting it in the end. You either call `sys.exit` outside of try-except or catch it explicitly and then re-raise.

Answer (score 1):

As a general comment, maybe you should look at using argparse. http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse Using argparse you don't have to manually inspect the argv array; argparse will do all the work for you.

Comment: Have since written many more python scripts and even better than docopt in my opinion is https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argh